# Cout not working after manipulating 2^18 floating point numbers

Tags: c++

I have 2 C arrays, both of size 2^17 and assign them some initial values. Right after I initialized them, I print a static string to cout and it works. But when I do it again with both of the arrays of size 2^18, it doesn't print anything. I store the 2^18 number inside an integer, which should be perfectly valid as the upper limit for integers is 2^31 or 2^32. I was wondering is it a problem about the environment?

I'm running Windows 10 with 8GB of RAM and use g++ for my C++ compiler. At first I suspected that the stack is being filled and that explains the cap off at 2^17, but it should give me a stack overflow error. However the program just exits gracefully without printing anything.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int N = 1 << 17;

    float x[N];
    float y[N];

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        x[i] = 1.0f;
        y[i] = 2.0f;
    }

    std::cout << "Done" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This isn't standard c++ code, VLA's aren't supported.

Comment: Do note that `int N = 1 << 17;

    float x[N];
    float y[N];` uses VLA's (variable length arrays) and is not standard C++.  You can use `-pedantic-errors` to stop the code from compiling.

Comment: Also, dont declare them on the stack it has limited space.

Comment: Remember that the default stack size on windows is 1MB.

Comment: I run it with `float x[2000000];` and it still doesn't work. I then run it again with `float *x = new float[2000000];` it then works. But why does this happen? Can this problem arise anywhere else?

Comment: `float x[2000000];` is too big for the stack.

Comment: It's better if you use `std::vector<float> x{N, 1.0f}`